# How to change variable in script?

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a bash shell script (AIX) that is the following..

```
for i in ('cat somefile.txt') do
do something with $i
end
```

The variables that get passed to $i are in the form of (content of somefile.txt)..

PUB.table1
PUB.CustTable

How can I remove the "PUB." text so that what's passed is only table1...CustTable....etc ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `${i#PUB.}` instead of just `$i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cut`:

```
cut -d '.' -f2 file | while read i; do echo "$i"; done
table1
CustTable
```

Or using **process substitution**:

```
while read i; do 
   echo "$i"
done < <(cut -d '.' -f2 file)
```

Comment: Thanks that works.. if the variable coming in had PUB.table1.list to remove the ".list" at the end of the text as well so I have "table1".. how can I adjust it to do so? Thank you!

Comment: `cut -d '.' -f2` will only print field #2 so only `table` will be output from `PUB.table1.list`